# Function not able to return values of list

Tags: python, list, function, return-value

I am trying to write a set of values to a file. Whilst, it prints the output successfully, when I try writing to file I get an error as `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'write'`. The code is follows:

```
time = open('Time_0', 'w+')

iterations = 0

def time():
    iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)
    for t in iteration_time:
        global iterations
        iterations = iterations +1
        return (iteration_time, iterations) 

with open(logFile,'r') as logFile_read:
    for line in logFile_read:
        if 'Time' in line:
            iterationTime = time()
            print iterationTime
            #time.write("%s" % iterationTime)
```

The output of the above is follows (as desired):

```
(['1'], 1)
(['2'], 2)
(['3'], 3)
(['4'], 4)
(['5'], 5)
(['6'], 6)
(['7'], 7)
(['8'], 8)
(['9'], 9)
(['10'], 10)
```

If I uncomment the last line, `time.write("%s" % iterationTime)` and run the same code, I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'write'.

It appears to be trivial, however I am unable to see whats happening here.
`

Comment: `time` is a function (which shadow outer scope `time` by the way) you need to write to a file object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the `time` function as a file - that's what the error message is telling you. The issue comes from the fact that you have first opened the `Time_0` file and stored it under `time` variable, then you are defining a `time` function which overwrites previously opened file.

Instead, you should do this:

```
iterations = 0

def time():
    iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)
    for t in iteration_time:
        global iterations
        iterations = iterations +1
        return (iteration_time, iterations) 

with open('Time_0', 'w+') as output_file:
    with open(logFile,'r') as logFile_read:
        for line in logFile_read:
            if 'Time' in line:
                iterationTime = time()
                print iterationTime
                output_file.write("%s" % iterationTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file `open('Time_0', 'w+')` and the function `def time` share the same name. Since you're defining the functon after opening the file, `time` refers to the function, not the file. Choose a different name for one of them.

Comment: I suggest choosing a different name for both of them. `time` is the name of a standard modules, so using it a variable name is not a good habit to get into. It doesn't matter here, but it would cause problems in a program that imports the `time` module. Also, using a standard module name as a variable name can be confusing (or at least annoying) to people reading the code.

Comment: Thanks every one out here for helping me on this trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

You use two objects that are referred to by the handle `time`, `time = open('Time_0', 'w+')` and `def time():`. Since `def time():` is the later declaration, `time`, at the point of calling `time.write`, refers to the function. Refactor the names.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `time` function after this: `time = open('Time_0', 'w+')`.

So, Python will have rebinded the name `time` to your function and, since your function has no `write` attribute, the error you got is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are running into a conflict using 'time' once as the handler for the file and secondly as a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = open('Time_0', 'w+')

iterations = 0

def time():
```

You have a variable called `time` and a function `time`. You have to change one of them.